# How to make 'First Row' the Header when saving data to SQL Server with Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Can someone let me know make the first row the header when saving to SQL Server with Databricks

I am currently using the following code to upload / save to SQL in Azure

```
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{DBServer}.database.windows.net:1433;database={DBDatabase};user={DBUser};password={DBPword};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
    
    
    df = spark.read.csv("/mnt/lake/RAW/OptionsetMetadata.csv")
    
    df.write.mode("overwrite") \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
        .option("dbtable", 'UpdatedProducts')\
        .save()
```

The table looks like the following after saving:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC driver creates the table according to the schema. It looks like that you're reading from the CSV file, and don't specify `.option("header", "true")` when reading. Just add this option to your read operation.